# QT 32 bit for VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have C++ project where I need to use QT in it, but the problem is that I'm using VS2017 and the project is 32 bit, but when I tried to install QT for VS2016 there where no 32 bit for it, is there any other source that has QT as 32 bit for VS2017?

Thanks

Comment: you can use MSVC2015 build, it will work  with VS2017

Comment: VC Runtime in MSVC 2017 is binary compatible with 2015

Comment: See discussion here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/80583/prebuild-qt-32-bit-versions-for-visual-studio-2017/6

Comment: "you can use MSVC2015 build, it will work with VS2017"  worked, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like I said in the comment and you confirmed it, MSVC2015 32 bit official prebuild version from the installer will work with VS2017 as VC runtime in MSVC 2017 is binary compatible with 2015 as explained here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/binary-compatibility-and-pain-free-upgrade-why-moving-to-visual-studio-2017-is-almost-too-easy/

If Qt team didn't provide MSVC2017 32 bit build it means that it just works.